# Tuning MySQL MyISAM for large joined updates

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, database-tuning, query-performance

I have a database with two tables that I would consider small. I need to update values on the larger of the two tables (1,100,000 rows, 75M MYD, 120M MYI) from the join of the two tables. The smaller of the two tables is (85,000 rows, 15M MYD, 11M MYI). Using EXPLAIN I've added indexes so that the SELECT that mirrors the UPDATE says it's using indexes on the larger of the two tables.

The `UPDATE` I'm trying to perform:

```
UPDATE membership M, 
    cover_details CD
SET M.option_id = CD.option_id,
    M.depind = if(CD.dependent_type=17, "P", "D"),
    M.cover_detail_id = CD.cover_detail_id,
    M.entity_common_id = CD.entity_common_id
WHERE M.runmonth BETWEEN CD.cover_start_date AND CD.cover_end_date
    AND M.memnum = CD.cover_number
    AND M.benfcnum = CD.dependent_number ;
```

The `EXPLAIN`:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key      | key_len | ref                                                       | rows  | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | CD    | ALL  | membership_idx,test          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                                                      | 84106 | Using where              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | M     | ref  | MemNum,MemNum_2,runmonth_idx | MemNum_2 | 18      | xxxxxxxxxx.cd.COVER_NUMBER,xxxxxxxxxx.cd.DEPENDENT_NUMBER |  1355 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

This query hasn't completed in  24 hours. The database is on an SSD too. What am I missing, surely this should only take a couple of minutes?

EDIT: Here are the two tables `create` statements:

```
-- The small table
CREATE TABLE `cover_details` (
  `COVER_DETAIL_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OPTION_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ENTITY_COMMON_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COVER_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPENDENT_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COVER_PREMIUM_AMOUNT` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPENDENT_TYPE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PENALTY_JOIN` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `COVER_START_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COVER_END_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APPLICATION_RECEIVE_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS_REASON` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SECURITY_GROUP_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EFFECTIVE_START_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EFFECTIVE_END_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `membership_idx` (`COVER_NUMBER`,`DEPENDENT_NUMBER`),
  KEY `pk_idx` (`COVER_DETAIL_ID`),
  KEY `ec_join_idx` (`ENTITY_COMMON_ID`,`COVER_START_DATE`,`COVER_END_DATE`,`EFFECTIVE_START_DATE`,`EFFECTIVE_END_DATE`,`PRODUCT_ID`),
  KEY `test` (`COVER_START_DATE`,`COVER_END_DATE`,`COVER_NUMBER`,`DEPENDENT_NUMBER`),
  KEY `test2` (`COVER_START_DATE`,`COVER_END_DATE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

-- the big table
CREATE TABLE `membership` (
  `MemNum` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currmemnum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcurrmemnum` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BenfcNum` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProdCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inccat` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `broker` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `runMonth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `depInd` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gndr` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yerun` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `morun` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NoPayInd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrpType` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RegDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResignDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyRiskRaised` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyLJPRaised` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyMSARaised` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyInvoiced` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthlyPaid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthsTillResig` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthsSinceReg` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empbranch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empgroup` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_claims_data` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'Yes',
  `entity_common_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_detail_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `MemNum` (`MemNum`,`BenfcNum`,`yerun`,`morun`),
  KEY `MemNum_2` (`MemNum`,`BenfcNum`,`runMonth`),
  KEY `ProdCode` (`ProdCode`),
  KEY `charcurrmemnum` (`charcurrmemnum`),
  KEY `empbranch` (`empbranch`),
  KEY `empgroup` (`empgroup`),
  KEY `broker` (`broker`),
  KEY `runmonth_idx` (`runMonth`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1093805 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: It would help of you added the actual `UPDATE` statement and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for both tables.

Comment: @ypercube: Done

Comment: How many rows will be updated? 30% or 90% or all? If it is going to be a big part of the table then using full table scan on the `M` table is probably preferable as now it does a full scan on `CD` and then randomly jumps around `M`to find matching rows.

Comment: 90% plus definitely. So I suppose the next question is how do I switch it round to do a full table scan on M?

Comment: As you have the condition `M.runmonth BETWEEN CD.cover_start_date AND CD.cover_end_date` the optimizer has not much chances to do that one well the other way around. But if you can do a covering index for `CD` (`Using index` in equivalent select  plan) and probably remove/ignore the index used on `M` so optimzer will not have a chance to go that way. For testing purposes I use `SELECT [STRAIGHT_JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) ..` but it is better to modify the query/indexes so the right plan is used even without it.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  (Recommend 20% of RAM.)  You understand that if you kill the query, it will have stored some updates, and left the others undone.  Recommend InnoDB.

Comment: Yuck:  `..._DATE varchar(21)`.  There are DATE and DATETIME datatypes that are much smaller.

Comment: @RickJames: I know :( Yuck, it's an inherited mess, and I'm busy trying to clean it up. Actually, that's what caused this mess. The UPDATE query was running fine, until I started messing with things. I'm doing my experiments in on a test system that mirrors the live system, except with half the RAM (8GB instead of 16GB), but both data stores are on SSDs. The key buffer size if 1970M on the test system, and 4096 on the live system.

Comment: According to the Explain, there is an estimated 84K * 1355 rows to look at to perform the query.  A thought... Walk through CD a little at a time, maybe a thousand MemNum's at a time.  It will take longer, but will be less invasive.  Here's a discussion of such: [big deletes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig), then adapt for `UPDATE`.

Comment: Finally found the problem. cover_details.COVER_NUMBER was an int(11) and many of the actual numbers were higher than 2417483648, and thus being truncated, meaning indices on COVER_NUMBER had far more duplicates to deal with. I'd missed the truncation warnings during the initial load.I've since changed it to bigint to account for the new higher membership numbers, and everything is hunky dory.